# Howto use makefile target with date?

Tags: makefile

I want something like this (date (from shell) in the target filename)

```
bakfile=mybackup.$(date +%Y%m%d).tar
$(bakfile):
     tar -cf $@ /source-dir
```

Or maybe with the date in the target spec?

```
mybackup.$(date +%Y%m%d).tar:
     tar -cf $@ /source-dir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a slightly greater effort, if you want to invoke shell commands from within a makefile:

```
bakfile=mybackup.$(shell date +%Y%m%d).tar
```

You can do it in the target name too, but I advise against that-- it's hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

A makefile is not a shell script.  A makefile can *contain* shell scripts, but you can't just write shell operations directly anywhere in a makefile and expect it to work like the shell.

I recommend:

```
date := $(shell date +%Y%m%d)
```

then use the variable `$(date)` wherever you want the date string.  Running it multiple times is a race condition risk, if you run it right around midnight the value might change between two different invocations.